# Loop through hash and find records to delete in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, ruby-hash

I am self-learning ruby by watching few videos and reading through blogs. I am currently in a situation where I have to parse the below parameters that I receive from an external CRM system into RUBY and find the relevant records from the database and delete them. It works well when I get a single record through below code:

```
temp_id = params[:salesforce_id]
Table.find_or_initialize_by(:id => temp_id).destroy
```

but I am struggling when I have to parse through multiple records like below, I get this error "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):" I might have to loop through this but any sample code will really help.

```
{"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}], "delete_record"=>{"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}]}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you have is a `Hash` (A) having a key `"_json"` and a key `"delete_record"` corresponding to a `Hash` (B) value. This `Hash` contains a key/value pair with `"_json"` as the key, and an `Array` as the value. This `Array` contains (several) `Hash` (C) objects.

What you want here is:

1. Get the value inside Hash (A) for key `"delete_record"`, which is Hash (B)
2. Get the value inside Hash (B) for key `"_json"`, which is an Array of Hash objects (C)
3. For each Hash (C) inside the Array, get the value for the key `"id"`.

You can do the following:

```
data = {
  "_json"=>
    [{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}], 
  "delete_record"=>
    {"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}]}
}
# step 1
data_for_delete_record_key = data['delete_record']
# step 2
array_of_hashes_with_id_key = data_for_delete_record_key['_json']
# step 3
ids_to_destroy = array_of_hashes_with_id_key.map { |hash| hash['id'] }
```

Then, you can simply use the following to destroy the matching records:

```
Table.where(id: ids_to_destroy).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
temp_id = {"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}], "delete_record"=>{"_json"=>[{"id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"2"}, {"id"=>"3"}]}}

temp_id["delete_record"]["_json"].pluck("id").each do |x|
  Table.find_or_initialize_by(:id => x.to_i).destroy
end
```